# match and replace substring issue in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, arguments, substring

So I have the following code

```
function format(){
  return arguments[0].replace(
        /%([0-9])/g,
    function($1){alert($1)}
    )

}

var sql=format("SELECT * FROM %1 WHERE id='%2' ", table, id);

var table= "table1";
var id = "F1542";
```

This alerts "%1" and "%2" but if I run this code:

```
function format(){
  return arguments[0].replace(
        /%([0-9])/g,
        "$1"
    )

}

var sql=format("SELECT * FROM %1 WHERE id='%2' ", table, id);

alert(sql);
```

I get "SELECT * FROM 1 WHERE id='2'", my aim is to get the matches without the % so that I can put use it in the arguments array (ie arguments[$1]), however everything I've tried has returned 'undefined' as it appears to be looking for arguments[%1] or arguments[%2].

Why is it that the first set of code returns the wrong values, but the second set does not? I was under the impression that the substring matches can be found by using $1, $2 etc...

PS sorry if I haven't explained this very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`replace()` will return a modified string (not the matches). In your first example you defined a function as a parameter and alerted the found variable. You could use `match()` to get a collection of just the matches, or if you combine your two examples you get something like this:

```
function format(){
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
    var sql = args[0];
    return sql.replace(
        /%([0-9])/g,
        function(matchVar,matchVal){
            return args[matchVal];
        });

}
```

The second parameter in the replacer function is the match value of the first match. You can use that value as an index to your argument array.

http://jsfiddle.net/N6S4Q/

Comment: Thanks this is great! But I still don't quite understand why in one example it returns the variables as "%1" and "%2" and in the other it returns in the replacement "1" and "2"?

Comment: The first parameter of the replace function is the string that cause the replace to kick in. The second parameter is the one that contains the [first] match.